# Returning `Maybe (Entity a)` from Esqueleto `LeftOuterJoin`

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

From a contrived `config/models` in a scaffolded site:

```
Inventory
  name        Text
  description Text
Container
  name        Text
ContainerSlot
  container   ContainerId
  item        InventoryId Maybe
```

Now, using Esqueleto, I want to use `LeftOuterJoin` to get the slots in a container, with the actual inventory empty if it has not been assigned.

```
selectContainerSlots containerKey = do
  stuff <- select $ from $ \(cs `LeftOuterJoin` i) -> do
    on $ cs ^. ContainerSlotItem ==. just (i ^. InventoryId)
    where_ $ cs ^. ContainerSlotContainer ==. val containerKey
    return (cs, i)
  return $ uncurry buildStuff <$> stuff
```

I would expect `buildStuff` to need the following signature due to the "outer" nature of the join:

```
buildStuff :: Entity ContainerSlot -> Maybe (Entity Inventory) -> Result
```

but find that it needs the following:

```
buildStuff :: Entity ContainerSlot -> Entity Inventory -> Result
```

Which causes runtime failures when (predictably) the the `Inventory` fields are filled with `NULL` values.

```
PersistMarshalError "field id: int64 Expected Integer, received: PersistNull"
```

Is there a way to project the `Entity Inventory` as an `Maybe (Entity Inventory)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably be marked a duplicate of [Outer Joins with Esqueleto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967523/outer-joins-with-esqueleto); however the difference is in the projection.

When dealing with any outer joins, all tables which may come back null should have **all** projections done with the `?.` syntax. This will force the table's entities to become `Maybe (Entity a)` So the solution to the above is

```
selectContainerSlots containerKey = do
  stuff <- select $ from $ \(cs `LeftOuterJoin` i) -> do
    on $ cs ^. ContainerSlotItem ==. i ?. InventoryId
    where_ $ cs ^. ContainerSlotContainer ==. val containerKey
    return (cs, i)
  return $ uncurry buildStuff <$> stuff
```

Additionally, if more than one table is chained; e.g.

```
select $ from $ \(cs `LeftOuterJoin` (i `InnerJoin` is)) -> do
```

Then **both** `i` and `is` (inventory SKU table) should be projected with that syntax:

```
  on $ i ?. InventoryId ==. is ?. InventorySkuItem
  on $ cs ^. ContainerSlotItem ==. i ?. InventoryId
```